# Is transit visa needed for travel from India to Toronto via London and Dublin?

Tags: transit-visas

I am Indian passport holder and travelling from India to Toronto via London and Dublin.
I have 2 stop flight from India with 2hours layover in London and then flight to Dublin with 3 hours layover and then to Toronto.
Is any transit visa needed? I check at https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no
and it says UK visa is not needed. But not sure in the case from london to dublin.

Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Why did you check "somewhere else" (as your link shows" instead of Ireland when you are going to Ireland from the UK  amd when the tool clearly asks if you are going to Ireland FROM THE UK or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Don't book that flight without a UK Standard Visitor visa. You [actually need a UK visa or an Irish visa endorsed BC BIVS](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/republic_of_ireland) to enter the UK traveling to Dublin. A transit visa is not good enough, as you have two stops in the Common Travel Area and must cross immigration in London.

Comment: Why would a [Visitor In Transit](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa) visa not suffice? (This is not the same as a Direct Airside Transit visa).

Comment: @HenningMakholm It wouldn't allow entry to Ireland, for one.

Comment: Would a Standard Visitor visa allow that?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, if it's endorsed BC BIVS.

Comment: And why would separate transit visas from the UK and Ireland not suffice?

Comment: @HenningMakholm It would, if you had _both_ such visas. That would be a real pain to actually go and apply for though, and it doesn't seem likely that anyone actually would.

Comment: This would of course be much, much easier if you were transiting ONLY through either London or Dublin. There are many direct London->Toronto flghts.